# Can I delete an entire partition in Windows Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have a set of rows in a partition that represents some cached data. I want to refresh that cache without any concern for what is already there. Is it possible to delete an entire partition without having to do any selects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can delete an entire *table* with one call, so you might consider making your partitions separate tables instead. (But, of course, you can't do cross-table queries.)

Comment: Any idea if that will change smarx? Why would you not be able to delete a partition? If you delete all of the entities in a partition, does the partition disappear too, or does it hang around forever empty?

Comment: Partitions don't exist except implicitly. (There's no such thing as an empty partition.) I have no idea if new features will be added in the future that let you do this.

Comment: OK - are you saying that a partition is nothing more than an indexed property of an entity? Because it has to exist (i.e. be referenced) somewhere outside of the entity itself, otherwise the performance improvements that happen with a query that all happens inside a partition wouldn't be possible, right? I had thought it was a physical thing, but I could also see how it could exist only in the entity row and an index...

Comment: The performance improvements come from things with the same partition key being served by the same server, which can happen when servers are each responsible for a partition range (e.g. A-M versus N-Z) Whether or not there are actually elements with a partition of "D" doesn't matter to those ranges.

Comment: 5 years later ... deleting the entire table is still the recommended pattern. See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#high-volume-delete-pattern