# Deleting hundreds of entities from Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

My coworker and I are currenty implementing a undo/redo feature for products. We're using the command pattern and saving every command (e.g. create component 'myFancyComponent') as a `TableStorageEntry` in the table 'ProductHistory'. `PartitionKey` in this table is the unique product name, `RowKey` is a unique identifier.

Problem is if a product gets deleted, it should also delete the whole history in the table storage. Using batch delete could get quite complicated, because there are several limitations:  max. 100 entities  or max. 4 MB (whatever is the lesser). Are there any best practices for this problem? Or is the only solution to query all entries and checking the size of the entries and than batch delete the right amount of entries?

I also found this similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393651/can-i-delete-an-entire-partition-in-windows-azure-table-storage) and considered to create a table for EACH product. It seems that there are some advantages of this approach:

- Selecting should be faster, because only one table will be queried
- Deleting is easy, just have to drop the whole table

Only disadvantage I found (in the 'WINDOWS AZURE TABLE' - white paper):

- Note that, when a table is deleted, the same table name cannot be recreated for at least 30 seconds, while the table is being garbage collected.

Are there any other (performance) issues, if I create several hundreds tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend the single table per product approach, as you pointed out it will quickly eliminate the need to batch up the transactions for delete and if you want to removethe 30 second limit, you just need to have an index table that stores the relationship between tables and their products. Then you can flag a product as deleted and reassign its table when its re-added. Thus allowing a simple by-pass of the 30 second limitation. Another approach (which I'd also recommend) is to decouple the addition of products so that is happens asyncronously, thus allow you to simply wait to create the table when the name is available again.

As for performance issues, there should be no issue even if you have thousands of tables providing you don't exceed the current 5k transactions per second limit on the Azure Storage Account. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second approach to solve the 30 second limitation? Do you suggest to create the product, but not the table, and create the table later when the old one has been deleted?

Comment: A solid approch to achieving scale is to stop doing operations "in real time". Queue the request for the creation of the new product, and simply send the user a message once it has been completed. Yes, we're used to instant gratification, but this approach is more scalable and would also address your 30 second wait time limit. :)